# Flashing folder with ? - what do I do if keyboard won't connect?

Tags: terminal

When I boot my computer it has a folder with a `?`.

It says that for me to reset it I must hit <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> but I cannot get my keyboard to connect.

What do I do now? Is there any other way for me to do a factory reset on my computer

Comment: What model Mac? What macOS version?

Comment: Plug a wired keyboard in.  A keyboard is a keyboard is a keyboard.